# Thrustmaster T150 not working with Forza Horizon 3

Tags: controllers, forza-horizon-3

I just bought a T150 to use with my PC. The pedals work, the wheel gives feedback, but when I turn, the car doesn't turn in game. I have tested the T150 with Project Cars 2 and I do not have any problem there. The T150 is in the list of supported wheels for Forza Horizon 3.

Additionally, I have also changed the controller settings in Forza Horizon 3 to Thrustmaster T150. Nothing works. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have other controllers attached to your PC? The game may be taking a different input preference, so try unplugging other controllers until the controller you are using starts responding. Some games might require a restart to fully recognise input method changes.

Comment: I don't have any other controllers attached. The only other input device is a keyboard, i can't technically remove that since it's a laptop. I've tried restarting the game multiple times, tried re-plugging in the wheel too. No change